# firebase log user out ref.unauth() did not work

Tags: authentication, firebase

I used the `$authWithPassword()` to login User, and it works fine. User can login, add content in the URL `(/index.html#/notebook)`. Then I used the `unauth()` to log user out, then redirect them to the login page. It does say use is logged out, and redirect the user to the login page `(/index.html#/login)`.

```
$scope.logOut = function(user) {
    logoutObj.unauth();
    console.log("User is logged out");
    $location.path('/login');
};
```

However, when I type the URL in browser again `(/index.html#/notebook)`, it shows this user is still logged in, and the content still available for the user.

It seems that the `unauth()` function does not really log out the user. Am i doing some thing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a simple repro case? I think it's likely that more code will be necessary to help you out. For example, what is `logoutObj` in the snippet above?

Comment: Let me see how i can create a similar scenario here. As for the logoutObj, var logoutObj = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/"); thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually `$unauth()` and not `unauth()`.

So change your code to this:

```
$scope.logOut = function(user) {

  logoutObj.$unauth();
  $location.path('/login');
};
```

Comment: thanks! unauth() actually works, i figured it is my internal route logic.

Comment: @Lisa I guess it's because it's the normal Firebase's API then. Which also works with angularfire.